# In Ext JS 4 grid with CellEditing plugin how to modify programatically an adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, grid-layout

Example is I have a CellEditing grid with one `checkcolumn` and another `numbercolumn` which is adjacent to it. I simply want when the `checkcolumn`'s row is checked/unchecked to modify the adjacent to it `numbercolumn`, ... respectively with 0 if unchecked, or another number if checked?

Answer (score 0):

To set a value on the adjacent cell, on the `checkcolumn` put this:

```
listeners : {
                            checkchange : function( CheckColumn, rowIndex, checked, eOpts ) {
                                var record = me.down('grid').getView().getRecord(rowIndex);
                                record.set('howMuch',0);
                            }
                        }
```